# Show HTML Table with Columns Dynamically From Stored Procedure Columns in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

I have one store procedure with some parameters. I want to show the HTML Table with column names should be the column names in stored procedure. How can i do that?

Example :
I am executing my stored procedure CALL_LIST, 2020-06-01, 2020-06-03. Here CALL_LIST is the stored procedure name and 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-03 is the parameters.

Result from stored procedure will be like this

```
    +---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+
    | Emp_Code | 01-06-2020 | 02-06-2020| 03-06-2020|
    +----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
    |       1  | 10:00      |   09:00   |   10:00   |
    |       2  | 10:00      |   10:00   |   10:00   |
    |       3  | 10:00      |   10:00   |   10:00   |
    +----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

My requirement is to create dynamic columns based on dates passed to the stored procedure.like here i passed 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-03, so 3 dynamic column need to generate with value. if i pass 2020-06-01 and 2020-06-10, 10 dynamic column have to generate and show value.

Example

```
<table>
<thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Emp Code</th>
      <?php $begin = new DateTime($datefrom);
        $end = new DateTime($dateto);
        $end = $end->modify('+1 day');
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); 
       foreach ($daterange as $date_val) {
        <th scope="col">$date_val->format('d-m-Y')</th>
        } ?>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><?php foreach ($data as $val) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td>{{$val->Emp_Code.}}</td>
   </tr><?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can i show the columns value from the stored procedure?

Comment: can you show me the query?

Comment: What query you need? In store procedure?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have a problem with getting the data from the database? Do you have a problem with turning the result into a html table? Clarify please

Comment: @ManUtd yes eloquent query?

Comment: this is my query 
$data = DB::select("SET NOCOUNT ON ;EXEC USP_Daily_TA_Punching_Detailswith_OT ?,?,?", array($employee,$datefrom,$dateto));

Comment: @MaartenVeerman there is no problem with the data returning from stored procedure and result into html table, my requirement is, show the html table column names dynamically from stored procedure.

Comment: i updated the requirement with some sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result

```
<table>
<thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Emp Code</th>
      <?php $begin = new DateTime($datefrom);
        $end = new DateTime($dateto);
        $end = $end->modify('+1 day');
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); 
       foreach ($daterange as $date_val) {
        <th scope="col">$date_val->format('d-m-Y')</th>
        }
            $dates = array();
            foreach ($daterange as $key => $date) {
                $dates[$key] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            }   ?>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody><?php foreach ($data as $val) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td>{{$val->Emp_Code}}</td>
      <?php foreach($dates as $val){
        <td>{{$row->{$val}}}</td>
           <?php } ?>
   </tr><?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```